# find the general solution of the ODE if the solution of the form $e^{ct}$ ,or some constant $c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that the equation

$$t\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-(1+3t)\frac{dy}{dt}+3y=0$$

has a solution of the form $e^{ct}$ , for some constant $c$, find the general solution.

**My idea**

i tried  inserted $y=e^{ct}$, because given equation has solution of the form $e^{ct}$

But i cant solve the equation can any one help me plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y'=ce^{ct}=cy$ and $y'' = cy' = c^2y $, so putting this solution in gives,
$$ (tc^2-(1+3t)c+3)y=0. $$
Since $y \neq 0$, $0 = tc^2-(1+3t)c+3 = (c-3)(ct-1), $ so $c=3$.

A linearly independent solution will be of the form $y(t) = u(t)e^{3t}$ for some nonconstant $u$. Differentiating gives
$$ y' = (u'+3u)e^{3t} \\
y'' = (u''+6u'+9u)e^{3t}
$$
Substituting this into the differential equation and dividing by $e^{3t}$ gives
$$ 0 = (u''+6u'+9u)t - (1+3t)(u'+3u) + 3u = tu''+ (3t-1) u' = 0, $$
which can be solved as a first-order equation for $u'$, and then integrated one more time to give $u$.

Comment: @Chappers....thank you so much..your rock